# Trouble Making A Bowling Calculator in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm attempting to make a bowling calculator that takes bowling scores from a text document, turns it into an array, and then computes the scores in Ruby. So far I have this, but when I try and run the code, I get a syntax error. Any help would be appreciated!

```
def read_ragged_array(the_filename)

  ragged_array = [nil]

  File.open(the_filename, "r") do |f|

    while line = f.gets
      fields = line.chomp.split(" ")
      row = [ ]

      fields.each do |field|
        row << field.to_i
      end

      ragged_array << row
    end
  end

  return ragged_array
end

def frame_score(the_frame, bonus1, bonus2)
  if (the_frame[0] == 10) #strike
      return 10 + bonus1 + bonus2
  elsif (the_frame[0] + the_frame[1] == 10) #spare
       return 10 + bonus1
  elsif (the_frame[0] + the_frame[1] < 10) #empty
      return the_frame[0] + the_frame[1]
  end

frames = read_ragged_array("game1.txt")

sco = 0

for i in 1..10
if frames[i][0] == 10 && frames[i+1][0] == 10
    bonus1 = 10
    bonus2 = frames[i+2][0]
  elsif frames[i][0] == 10 && frames[i+1][0] < 10
    bonus1 = frames[i+1][0]
    bonus2 = frames[i+1][1]
  elsif frames[i][0] + frames[i][1] == 10
    bonus1 = frames[i+1][0]
    bonus2 = 0
  else
    bonus1 = 0
    bonus2 = 0
end
end

frame_score(frames[i], bonus1, bonus2) + sco = x
print x

end
```

The error returned is:

```
bowling.rb:65: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

Update: I'm no longer seeing the syntax error, but I get no output... Thanks for helping my newbie self! (code has been updated to reflect)

Comment: You should also paste in the syntax error :)

Comment: Sorry about that! Here we go: "bowling.rb:65 syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end"

Comment: Run `ruby -w <my_file_path>` and read that output, especially stuff like "mismatched indentation"

Comment: Interesting, there were two indentation errors that I fixed, however, now nothing it outputting.

Comment: It's like you're expecting Ruby to be like Python. `if` needs a corresponding `end`.

Comment: I see that — I've triple checked all of my (now updated) code, and am not seeing any ends. Unless I'm wrong. Updated code is in the question. Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error is in this line (should be `f.gets`):

```
while line = f.getsa
```

And an `end` on the last line.

Comment: Thanks for catching this! I'm still getting the same error though.

Comment: Updated, you need an `end` on the last line

Comment: There is an end on the last line, hence why the error is puzzling me. Again, much appreciated!

Comment: It needs another one after the for loop

Comment: Interesting, it's not giving me an error any more but nothing is outputting. Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong? Thanks again, you're truly helping a beginner out.